# Convert the code to python class

Tags: python

I have wrote a code for password checker with simple for loop- Now I am trying to do the same using Python Class.

```
pwd = raw_input('Please enter the passowrd: ')

flag_upp = 0
flag_num = 0
flag_len = 0

for i in pwd:
    if(i.isupper()):
        flag_upp = 1
    if(i.isdigit()):
        flag_num = 1
if(len(pwd)>7):
    flag_len = 1

total_flag = flag_upp + flag_num + flag_len
flags = [flag_upp,flag_num,flag_len]
notations = ['Upper case missing','Number missing','Length must be minimum 8 chars']

if(total_flag==3):
    print 'Password is valid!'
else:
    print 'Invalid password!'
    for i in range(0,len(flags)):
        if(flags[i]==0):
            print notations[i]
        else:
            pass
```

What should be the structure if i do this using class of python.

Comment: My request - Please don't ask to convert the code. Please first try on your end. Put that code here and the ask for help. Just converting above code to class won't help you in long term.

Comment: Object Oriented Programming in vast concept. Google it.. Learn it... Try it

Comment: Thanks - I did try and able to create the below one.. its working -

Answer (score 1):

```
class password: 
    def __init__ (self, pwd): #Self is the automatic object
        self.pwd = pwd
        print 'password created'

    def validate(self):
        flag_upp = 0
        flag_num = 0
        flag_len = 0

        for i in self.pwd:
            if(i.isupper()):
                flag_upp = 1
            if(i.isdigit()):
                flag_num = 1
            if(len(self.pwd)>7):
                flag_len = 1

        total_flag = flag_upp + flag_num + flag_len
        flags = [flag_upp,flag_num,flag_len]
        notations = ['Upper case missing','Number missing','Length must be minimum 8 chars']

        if(total_flag==3):
            print 'Password is valid!'
        else:
            print 'Invalid password!'
            for i in range(0,len(flags)):
                if(flags[i]==0):
                    print notations[i]
            # else:
            #   pass

 D = str(raw_input('Password:'))
 p1 = password(D)
 p1.validate()
```